# How to add fictional rows to an SQL results in Oracle without à grouping

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting

here is my issue, I'm working on an existing big report and they want me to add fictional rows with specifics values each time row in database meet a condition (let's say status = Canceld)
I simplified the query (1000 lines of SQL Code) to this :

if I have two table A and B :

```
Table A
Name            Status              Estimated       Real  
COMPANY A       Completed           $50.00          $50.00   
COMPANY B       Canceled            $0.00           $0.00  
COMPANY C       Not Approved        $100.00     $0.00  
COMPANY D       Withdrawn           $20.00          $10.00   
COMPANY E       Not Approved        $0.00           $0.00  
COMPANY F       Canceled            $1,000.00       $1,000.00
---------------------------------------------------------------

Table B
Name            Status              Estimated       Real  
COMPANY G       In Progress         $50.00          $20.00   
COMPANY H       Not Started         $20.00          $0.00  
COMPANY H       Passed              $100.00     $100.00  
COMPANY I       Approved            $20.00          $00.00   
COMPANY J       Canceled            $14.00          $6.00  
COMPANY A       Scheduled           $2,000.00       $2,000.00
```

and the query is like that :

```
SELECT * from (
SELECT NAME,STATUS,ESTIMATED,REAL from A
UNION ALL
SELECT NAME,STATUS,ESTIMATED,REAL from B
) order by name
```

and the results are like that :

```
Name            Status              Estimated       Real  
COMPANY A       Completed           $50.00          $50.00   
COMPANY A       Scheduled           $2,000.00       $2,000.00
COMPANY B       Canceled            $0.00           $0.00  
COMPANY C       Not Approved        $100.00     $0.00  
COMPANY D       Withdrawn           $20.00          $10.00   
COMPANY E       Not Approved        $0.00           $0.00  
COMPANY F       Canceled            $1,000.00       $1,000.00
COMPANY G       In Progress         $50.00          $20.00   
COMPANY H       Not Started         $20.00          $0.00  
COMPANY H       Passed              $100.00     $100.00  
COMPANY I       Approved            $20.00          $00.00   
COMPANY J       Canceled            $14.00          $6.00
```

now what I need to do is insert fictional rows whenever the Status is Canceled like that :
for each row where Status = Canceled add a row with same Name and Estimated column, Status Scheduled and Real = 0. the result should look like : (I added ** before the fictional rows)

```
Name            Status              Estimated       Real  
COMPANY A       Completed           $50.00          $50.00   
COMPANY A       Scheduled           $2,000.00       $2,000.00
COMPANY B       Canceled            $0.00           $0.00  
**COMPANY B     Scheduled           $0.00           $0.00**  
COMPANY C       Not Approved        $100.00     $0.00  
COMPANY D       Withdrawn           $20.00          $10.00   
COMPANY E       Not Approved        $0.00           $0.00  
COMPANY F       Canceled            $1,000.00       $1,000.00
**COMPANY F     Scheduled           $1,000.00       $0.00**
COMPANY G       In Progress         $50.00          $20.00   
COMPANY H       Not Started         $20.00          $0.00  
COMPANY H       Passed              $100.00     $100.00  
COMPANY I       Approved            $20.00          $00.00   
COMPANY J       Canceled            $14.00          $6.00  
**COMPANY J     Scheduled           $14.00          $0.00**
```

I tried a join or UNION with dual but I don't figure out what's missing. thank you a lot

Comment: is there a field giving the order between the different status of a company? Or the Canceled status doesnt have to be the last for the creation of the fictional row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give this a try, note that C is an inline view which is used to select the fictional row and does a union with your existing resultset.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT C.name, 
               'Scheduled' AS status, 
               0           AS estimated, 
               0           AS real 
        FROM   (SELECT name, 
                       status 
                FROM   a 
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT name, 
                       status 
                FROM   b) C 
        WHERE  C.status = 'Canceled') 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT name, 
        status, 
        estimated, 
        real 
 FROM   a 
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT name, 
        status, 
        estimated, 
        real 
 FROM   b) 
ORDER  BY name, 
          estimated DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple use your query in a `with` subquery

```
with tab as (
SELECT * from (
SELECT "Name","Status" ,"Estimated","Real" from A
UNION ALL
SELECT "Name","Status" ,"Estimated","Real" from B
)
)
select * from tab
```

and add a new `UNION ALL` query from the same source filtering only `cancelled` rows and managing the columns as required:

```
with tab as (
SELECT * from (
SELECT "Name","Status" ,"Estimated","Real" from A
UNION ALL
SELECT "Name","Status" ,"Estimated","Real" from B
)
)
select * from tab
union all
select "Name", 'Scheduled', "Estimated", 0 "Real"
from tab where "Status" = 'Canceled';
```

Note that `real` is not the best choice for column name as it is a **reserved word**, so I must enclose it in double quotes.

Comment: that worked just fine, thank you, now I have to adjust this solution to my thousand line query, thank you very much

Comment: @Slifer the `with` clause  (CTE) makes it possible to write the 1000 line `union` query only *once*  and *use it twice*. Contrary to the solution you [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59492604/4808122), where you must copy the large `union` in two places;)

Answer (score 0):

- sample data is from line #1 to 13
- union (you already have) is the `tabunion` CTE (lines #14 - 18)
- fetch canceled names that should become "scheduled" (lines #20 - 24)
- final result is yet another union

---

```
SQL> with
  2  taba (name, status, estimated, real) as
  3    (select 'A', 'completed'   ,   50,   50 from dual union all
  4     select 'B', 'canceled'    ,    0,    0 from dual union all
  5     select 'C', 'not approved',  100,    0 from dual union all
  6     select 'F', 'canceled'    , 1000, 1000 from dual
  7    ),
  8  tabb (name, status, estimated, real) as
  9    (select 'G', 'in progress',   50,   20 from dual union all
 10     select 'I', 'approved'   ,   20,    0 from dual union all
 11     select 'J', 'canceled'   ,   14,    6 from dual union all
 12     select 'A', 'scheduled'  , 2000, 2000 from dual
 13    ),
 14  tabunion as
 15    (select name, status, estimated, real from taba
 16     union all
 17     select name, status, estimated, real from tabb
 18    ),
 19  -- canceled statuses that should become "scheduled"
 20  canc as
 21    (select name, 'scheduled' status, estimated, 0 real
 22     from tabunion
 23     where status = 'canceled'
 24    )
 25  -- for final result, union A, B and CANC
 26  select name, status, estimated, real
 27    from tabunion
 28  union all
 29  select name, status, estimated, real
 30    from canc
 31  order by name;

N STATUS        ESTIMATED       REAL
- ------------ ---------- ----------
A completed            50         50
A scheduled          2000       2000
B canceled              0          0
B scheduled             0          0
C not approved        100          0
F canceled           1000       1000
F scheduled          1000          0
G in progress          50         20
I approved             20          0
J scheduled            14          0
J canceled             14          6

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```